# How to make elements float up when deleting an element above with ngAnimate

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-animate

I have a list of Elements which I can add and delete.

```
<div id="container" ng-repeat="element in elements">
    <button ng-click="remElement($index)">x</button>
</div>
```

Now as you can see in my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TipNo1/kpwm7rro/), when you delete an element, it goes up and disappears. I find it unpleasant how the element under the element which was deleted waits till the animation is over and then hops up. Is there a way to make the element float up smoothly instantly when the element above starts to go up?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but I think you can easily accomplish that by adding height into the container css elements, like this:

```
#container.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
#container.ng-leave {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
    height:80px;
}

#container.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
#container.ng-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    top: -50px;
    height:0px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: is there also another way? In a more complex situation I cant set the height to 0px because of the padding, so it doesnt work.